# Get a value from a PHP Page to a Javascript in Another Page Issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

this time i am having a problem to get a value of a php file where the goal is make a query (that part is done), validate if the query doesn't work, return false or else true.

That file is called into a javascript var to get the true/false value, but it doesn't work. I know that i'm failing because i printed the boolean value and alert shows "[object][object]".

Here is my HTML file

```
<form class="form-inline" id="formpqrs1" onSubmit="Validate()" method="get">
                       <label> <h4><b>Information</b></h4></label>
                       <br> 
                       <select id="s2" name="s2" style="min-width:25%"></select>
                       <br><br>   
            <label><h4><b>Insert Element Name</b></h4></label>
            <br>
            <input name="Nombre" id="Lugarpqrs" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="NOMBRE" required>
            <br> <br>

           <div id="motivos"> 
             <label> <h4><b>Choose Type:</b></h4></label>
             <br>
             <div class=radio-inline>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="tipomotivo" id="tipomotivo" value="1"><h5>Type 1</h5>
              </label>
             </div>
             <div class=radio-inline>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="tipomotivo" id="tipomotivo" value="2"><h5>Type 2</h5>
              </label>
             </div>
             <div class=radio-inline>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="tipomotivo" id="tipomotivo" value="3"><h5>Type 3</h5>
              </label>
             </div>
             <div class=radio-inline>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="tipomotivo" id="tipomotivo" value="4"><h5>Type 4</h5>
              </label>
             </div>
             <br><br>
          </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </form>
```

Here my Javascript file where i get the value of the php file, i validate from a radio button, then i create a var to get the value of the php file where the query is done.

```
function Validate(){

if($("#opcion:checked").val() === "1"){
     var validar = false;
     var validar = $.get("validaciones/Validar_Ubicacion.php?lugar="+$("#Lugarpqrs").val()+"");

    if(!validar){
        $.get("php/Ingresar_tipo.php?lugar="+$("#Lugarpqrs").val()+"");
        alert("Success" + validar);
    }

    else{
        alert("Element Already Exist in DB" + validar); 
    }
}
```

Here is my php file

```
<?php 
$lugar=$_GET["lugar"];

$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass,$bd) 
or die("ERROR");

$confirmacion = false;

$sql = "SELECT *  FROM `lugar` WHERE  `nombre` = '".$lugar."'";
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die();

$close = mysqli_close($conexion) 
or die("ERROR");

if(!$sql){
    echo $confirmacion;
}

else{
    $confirmacion = true;
    echo $confirmacion;
}
?>
```

The last part if/else is where i validate if query fails that means the element doesn't exist then return $confirmacion value which is false or else $confirmacion = true which means element already exist and show an alert message in the script that is on another page.

Previously i tested other validations like the query and if/else validations of the radio button (first if validation) and it works, so, the problem is in my var validar, maybe i'm doing wrong when i get the value from my php file.

As always, thanks for your time and attention, all answers are welcome to me.

Good day.

Comment: add html to your question

Comment: Added, but i tried without the validation and it works good, the problem is when i get the value of the php file, i tested to show the value of the var validar on alert and it shows the value "[object][object]" instead of true/false.

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');echo json_encode($confirmacion);` to retrun from php for javascript

Comment: I see, interesting, i am gonna try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your logic inside the jquery's .get function (since it's asynchronous.

Update your PHP file to output string "true" and "false" (best practice is to use JSON format & header) - this may work for you.

I updated for you your Javascript file:

```
function Validate(){

if($("#opcion:checked").val() === "1"){
     var validar = false;
     $.get("validaciones/Validar_Ubicacion.php?lugar="+$("#Lugarpqrs").val()+"",

    function(data){

    if(data=="true"){
        $.get("php/Ingresar_tipo.php?lugar="+$("#Lugarpqrs").val()+"");
        alert("Success" + validar);
    }

    else{
        alert("Element Already Exist in DB" + validar); 
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Oh i see, and how is with JSON format? or an example to see how is it? thanks for your answer, really useful :)

Comment: add "json" after ` *** function(data){ *** }, json **** `  and the reponse PHP script should return `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');echo json_encode($booleanvalue);`

Comment: I tested the solution and it worked, thank you very much :)